# Increment a value on a model in Rails from any controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning rails and im trying to find the right way to increment a "Points" value on the User model regardless of scope. Should I just put it in the model file or a helper...?
Im not really sure where this belongs.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    before_create :create_remember_token
    acts_as_messageable

    has_secure_password

    has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :message_constraint, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :pictures
    validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, on:    :create }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, presence: true
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

    def User.new_remember_token
      SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def User.hash(token)
      Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
    end

    def name
      return '#{first_name}'
    end

    private
      def create_remember_token

      end

  end
```

Comment: Can you provide some existing code? Or even some pseudo-code?

Comment: Ah, I don't really have any for this feature yet. I'm just trying to figure out if it should be a helper or a method on the model.

Comment: Is this a transient value that's only temporary or something that exists as a persisted field in the Users table?

Comment: Its something thats persisted.

Comment: So would I just add that as a public method on the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a field in the User table you don't need to add any methods to the User model. Part of the Rails Magic™ is that it will automatically intercept methods to get and set those values and handle everything behind the scenes for you.

Looking at [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment), it seems like you should be able to do the following, given `@user` is an instance of the `User` class

```
@user.increment(:points)
```

Note that you can increment by more than 1 at a time, there is a second argument that you can pass in, but if you do not it simply defaults to 1.

EDIT: [Craig Kochis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631816/craig-kochis) notes that you either need to use the destructive `!` version of the increment method or call `@user.save` to persist the change.

Comment: If it doesn't work, put a comment here with what you're seeing and I'll help you work through it.

Comment: Thanks. I've actually closed down my workstation for the night, but Ill be sure to test it tomorrow :)

Comment: Just a heads up that increment does not persist the value in the database. You would need to call `@user.increment!(:points)`, or save the model after incrementing: `@user.increment(:points)` then `@user.save`